# Add uniqueness to a MySQL index

Tags: mysql, database, unique-key

There are many answers on how to remove the uniqueness of a key from MySQL, but nothing on how to add it.

Is there any way to turn a KEY into a UNIQUE KEY?

Comment: Give us an example of what you mean, struggling to guess at where you are going with this.

Comment: As in ALTER TABLE DROP KEY mykey; ALTER TABLE ADD UNIQUE KEY mykey, except without having to actually drop and re-generate the key.

Answer (score 0):

```
ALTER TABLE sales.order ADD UNIQUE(order_ref);
```

example stolen from http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/alter-table.html

Comment: This is the equivalent of running ALTER TABLE sales.order ADD UNIQUE order_ref_2 (order_ref); It will only make a new index, not alter the current one.

Answer (score 0):

More visual way with phpmyadmin, click **structure** while browsing the table. At the bottom of the page there are "Indexes" section, you can manage key and types with edit button.

Comment: Yes, but trying to change a key only does DROP KEY and then ADD KEY, which is (AFAIK) very expensive on large tables.